# Unexpected EOF while Parsing in Python Random Sentence Generator

Tags: python, random, input

I am running Python 2.7.12 with no extensions. This is my code, and I am getting an Unexpected EOF while parsing.

```
import random
import sys
import time
print("Welcome to the weird sentence generator.")
wantto = True
print("Press enter to generate a weird sentence. Press Q to quit.")
while True:    
    senttype = random.randint(1,5)
    VERBS = ["dying", "farting","eating","pooping","pooing","drinking","running","walking","dancing","singing","learning","burping","digesting","fighting","licking","flying","smoking","mating","reproducing","playing","thinking","peeing","typing","programming","sitting","standing","slipping","ice-skating","skating","riding","murdering","killing","snoring","watching","looking","sprinting","jogging","opening","closing","calling","drawing","painting","washing","cleaning","cooking","kissing","snogging","showering","bathing","lifting","listening","conjuring","writing","composing","socializing","talking","lip-syncing to music.ly","being annoying","wrestling","practicing martial art","meeting people","skateboarding","riding a bike","proposing to his girlfriend","trying to get good at Game of War because he kept getting rekt by TheLegend27","clicking stuff on his PC","clicking his tongue","whistling","clapping","helping someone kill themself","failing to think of examples for this random sentence program"]
verb = random.choice(VERBS)
VERBSTWO = ["die","fart","eat","poop","poo","drink","run","walk","dance","sing","learn","flirt","digest","fart","eat","fly","burp","dig","smoke","lick","snore","kiss","snog","vomit","throw up","play","think","pee","type","arrest","program","sit","stand","lie down","slip","ice-skate","skate","skateboard","ride","murder","kill","slaughter","snore","watch","look","sprint","jog","open","close","call","drag","draw","paint","photograph","wash","clean","cook","bathe","solve"]
NOUNS = ["pig","cow","chicken","camel","man","woman","girl","boy","mouse","house","box","computer","fox","omelette","egg","sandwich","mouse pad","remote control","TV remote","screen","frame","statue","painting","wall","floor","ceiling","window","table","chair","TV","xBox 360","Wii","Playstation 1","Playstation 2","Playstation 3","Playstation 4","xBox 1","Nintendo DS","Game Boy","Nintendo 3DS","charger","phone","telephone","iPhone","iPad","iPod","flower","tree","bush","president","prime minister","baby","mirror","cupboard","wardrobe","walrus","goat","koala","sea lion","fish","goldfish","DVD","DVD player","USB","bed","bedroom","toilet","bathroom","living room","room","kitchen","oven","fridge","freezer","gate","snake","python","document","sentence","windowsill","shower","dining room","napkin","fork","knife","spoon","sugar cube","sugar","salt","potato","carrot","cucumber","tomato","soup","vinegar","crisp","chip","French fry","egg","pillow","blanket","matress","sheet","file","user","rapper","singer","runner","builder","zombie","wizard","engineer","monkey","gorilla","baboon","skeleton","tiger","pop star"]
noun = random.choice(NOUNS)
ADVERBS = ["slowly","quickly","stupidly","cleverly","harshly","horribly","beautifully","skillfully","easily","difficultly","nicely","pleasantly","surprisingly","prettily","artfully","craftily","hungrily","thirstily","greedily","selfishly","unselfishly","kindly","generously","randomly","idiotically","periodically","logically","illogically","controversially","sickeningly","poorly"]
adverb = random.choice(ADVERBS)
ADJECTIVES = ["fat","thin","weird","strange","normal","average","random","legendary","horrible","vile","cruel","ugly","pretty","beautiful","disgusting","pleasant","surprising","nice","artful","pretty","crafty","hungry","thirsty","greedy","selfish","unselfish","kind","generous","thorough","idiotic","stupid","obese","logical","illogical","controversial","sickening","poor","dumb"]
adjective = random.choice(ADJECTIVES)
adjective2 = random.choice(ADJECTIVES)
noun2 = random.choice(NOUNS)
COLOURS = ["blue","green","maroon","yellow","pink","purple","white","black","brown","hazel","red","orange","turquoise","peach","tan","chestnut","chocolate"]
colour = random.choice(COLOURS)
verb2 = random.choice(VERBSTWO)
what = input()
if senttype == 1:
    print("The",noun,"was",adverb,verb,"in the",adjective,"park, but the", adjective2,colour,noun2,"wanted him to", verb2+".")
if senttype == 2:
    print("My favourite",noun,"is the",adjective,colour,"one",adverb,verb,"in a",noun2+"!")
if senttype == 3:
    print("I",verb2,"with a",adjective,noun,"frequently and",adverb+".")
if senttype == 4:
    print("Although",verb,"is",adjective+", the",noun,"was too",adjective2,"to",verb2,"it.")
if senttype == 5:
    print("The",adjective,colour,noun,"is good at",verb,"and likes to",adverb,verb2,"every day!")
if what =="Q" or what == "q":
    sys.exit()
```

Thanks if you could help, and yes, I will 'accept' answers if you want some reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your identation was off; there the correct indentation (abbreviated all your lists to increase visibility...):

```
import random
import sys
import time
print("Welcome to the weird sentence generator.")
wantto = True
print("Press enter to generate a weird sentence. Press Q to quit.")
while True:
    senttype = random.randint(1,5)
    VERBS = ["dying", ...,"failing to think of examples for this random sentence program"]
    verb = random.choice(VERBS)
    VERBSTWO = ["die",...,"solve"]
    NOUNS = ["pig",...,"pop star"]
    noun = random.choice(NOUNS)
    ADVERBS = ["slowly",...,"poorly"]
    adverb = random.choice(ADVERBS)
    ADJECTIVES = ["fat",...,"dumb"]
    adjective = random.choice(ADJECTIVES)
    adjective2 = random.choice(ADJECTIVES)
    noun2 = random.choice(NOUNS)
    COLOURS = ["blue"...,"chocolate"]
    colour = random.choice(COLOURS)
    verb2 = random.choice(VERBSTWO)
    what = input('waiting for input')
    if senttype == 1:
        print("The",noun,"was",adverb,verb,"in the",adjective,"park, but the", adjective2,colour,noun2,"wanted him to", verb2+".")
    if senttype == 2:
        print("My favourite",noun,"is the",adjective,colour,"one",adverb,verb,"in a",noun2+"!")
    if senttype == 3:
        print("I",verb2,"with a",adjective,noun,"frequently and",adverb+".")
    if senttype == 4:
        print("Although",verb,"is",adjective+", the",noun,"was too",adjective2,"to",verb2,"it.")
    if senttype == 5:
        print("The",adjective,colour,noun,"is good at",verb,"and likes to",adverb,verb2,"every day!")
    if what =="Q" or what == "q":
        break
```